# UITableView not updating on reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two tableview on the screen. I have set delegate & datasource for both tableview. Lets have consider one table to show main filters & on click of particular cell/filter i have to reload subfilters in second tableview.

So i tried very simple solutions, `didSelectRowAt`,

```
subfilterTableView.reloadData()
```

Even i have tried by calling on main thread too,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    subfilterTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Still its not reloading the `subfilterTableView`.

> > I know this beginUpdates() & endUpdates() method are only for to insert & delete cells still i have reload in between beginUpdates() & endUpdates() it make crash as it is accepted.

I know this is stupid question but i have tried every possible simpler solutions.

**Following are the some conditions which i come across:**

1. Sometime data get populated on second click
2. Sometime data get populated after 3-5 seconds
3. Data get populated on refresh of tableview too

> > irony is Data get properly populated on real device

**Following is my code:**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            return filters.count
        }
        else{
            return subFilters.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            let filter = filters[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
            cell.labelFilter.text = filter["filterName"] as? String
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubFilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SubFilterTableViewCell
            cell.labelSubfilter.text = subFilters[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
    }


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if tableView.tag == 1 {

            let selectedCell:FilterTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! FilterTableViewCell
            selectedCell.labelFilter.textColor = UIColor.black
            selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            subFilters = filters[indexPath.row]["subFilterValue"] as! [String]


            self.tableViewSubfilters.reloadData()



//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                self.tableViewSubfilters.reloadData()
//            }
//            tableViewSubfilters.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
        }

    }
```

Comment: how are you filtering the data, issue might be that data is not filtered and sub table is showing the same data as before reloading.

Comment: No man i am doing it correct, Even my cellForRowAtIndexPath is calling perfectly what number of cell i am returning but data is not getting populated instantly, sometime it get populate after 3-4 second where i am not using any timer, not performing another any execution.

Comment: can you show up your classes here?

Comment: Can you share more of your code? How are the tables initialized, are you setting the correct number of sections & rows? Is `didSelectRowAt` being called?  Anything you have tried to solve it?

Comment: post code where filtering and reloading is being done.

Comment: Hello Guys i have posted my code.

Comment: You are testing this in simulator or in real device?

Comment: That's all the table related code? Are you setting for instance, the sections number?

Comment: I am testing it on the simulator iPhone 7(ios 11.2)

Comment: Test it on real device it will work

Comment: @Raspu Both table having only one section.

Comment: hey @VanditMehta its working on device . But i am surprised how it is possible then why its not working on simulator

Comment: @user7555810 Can you set breakpoints on `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` and inspect what is in the data that you are providing? Maybe add this info to the question (like, when I call `reloadData`, `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and I can see the correct subfiltered data there).

Comment: Yes its calling perfectly all data i am filtering correctly, same code perfectly working on real device. Now i am just curious to know why its working on real device & why not on simulator?

Comment: @user7555810 : It's happening some time in simulators, from xcode 9.0 and above

Comment: @user7555810 Have you checked whether the second table fetches after second click or clicking on screen again? Keep `tableViewSubfilters.reloadData()` in  `DispatchQueue.main.async` as it should be called on main thread.

Comment: Yes when i refresh the tableview data getting populated on simulator or sometime data get populated after 3-5 seconds after reloadData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code does not have any issue

Just run it on real device instead of simulator

Comment: thank you Yes it is working on real device, but we have to find exact solution why not working on simulator.

Comment: Yes, you can try it but as i said in comment "It's happening some time in simulators, from xcode 9.0 and above"

Answer (score 0):

Do check the `Datasource` and `Delegates` of your second `tableview`.

```
subfilterTableView.dataSource = self
subfilterTableView.delegate   = self
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I have set datasource & delegate for both table

Comment: it seems to me that something is wrong with the delegate of your second tableview, have you tried didset to set the datasource and delegate of second tableview. Try setting the datasource and delegate with didSet in your tableview outlet and lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

Put in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.datasource = self
}
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I have set datasource & delegate for both table

Comment: @user7555810 Your question didn't specify where you configure the tableViews, so please be as specific as possible when writing the question, always try to share as much code as you can.